# jQuery Mobile opening popups in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with jQuery Mobile popups. In my website, I have a page with two popups (popup1 and popup2).
In popup1, I have a button (`sendConfirm`). When user click on this button, I call function `callRequest()` with AJAX-request. In this function, on success AJAX, I close popup1 and after `300ms-timeout`, open popup2. Code below:

```
function callRequest() {
    showLoadIcon();
    var msg = '....';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '.....',
        data: msg,
        success: function (resp) {
            hideLoadIcon();
            $('#popup1').popup('close');
            if (resp.success == true) {
                if (resp.ms_id != null) {
                    $('#code').val('');
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('#popup2').popup('open')
                    }, 300);
                } else {
                    $('#text').text("Received!");
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('#popup3').popup('open');
                        clearRqt();
                    }, 100);
                }
            } else {
                $('#text').text(data.error.text);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#popup3').popup('open')
                }, 100);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, str) {
            hideLoadIcon();
            $('#popup1').popup('close');
            $('#text').text("Error!");
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#popup3').popup('open')
            }, 100);
        }
    });
}
```

I tested it on Android Browser, Firefox and Google Chrome. On Android Browser and Firefox, it works correctly. When I used Google Chrome, popup2 didn't open. 
How can I decide this problem?

HTML code:

```
<div data-role="page" id="requestPage" data-theme="b">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-theme="b">
            <a href="#main" data-rel="back" data-transition="fade"><i class='icon-angle-left'></i></a>
            <h1>Request</h1>
        </div>

         <div data-role="content" > 

            <div data-role="popup" id="popup1" data-dismissible="false" data-position-to="window" style="background-color:#000000; border:5px double #C0FF3E;">
                <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
                    <h1>Confirm request</h1>
                </div>        
                 <div data-role="content" id="conConfirm"> 
                    ....
                </div>
            </div>

            <div data-role="popup" id="popup2" data-dismissible="false" data-position-to="window" style="background-color:#000000; border:5px double #C0FF3E;">
                <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
                    <h1>Enter code</h1>
                </div>        
                 <div data-role="content"> 
                    <form id="frmRqtSMS">
                       ...
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>  


            <div data-role="popup" data-dismissible="false" id="popup3" data-position-to="window" style="background-color:#000000; border:5px double #C0FF3E;">
                <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
                    <h1>Info</h1>
                </div>        
                <div data-role="content"> 
                    <div>
                        <p id="text"></p>
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="button" id="popupClick" onclick="if(num != '') $.mobile.changePage('#templates'); else $('#popup3').popup('close');">Apply</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <form id="sendRequest" method="post"> 
                ...
            </form>
         </div>
</div>
```

Can anybody help with this problem? I saw many questions with it, but there are no solutions.

Comment: Could you add the html code and maybe tell us if you get an error message on Chrome's console?Thanks

Comment: Updated with HTML code.

Comment: How can I watch error console on mobile device?

Comment: You can set up remote debugging as per the docs here: [Chrome remote debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging). This can help immensely with issues like this. Let us know how you get on.

Comment: I tested my website on computer (Firefox, Chrome). There are no error messages on console. If you think, that on mobile device will be errors on console, I can do remote debugging. Are you sure that it will help?

Comment: More info: if I try to open popup2 from popup1 without setTimeout(), it will not open in all browsers.